# Using Bootstrap's collapse class on element that needs to be display: inline-block when visible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [Bootstrap](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp)'s class `collapse` to hide an `<a>` element with a container on a page when first loaded. At the same time I set in my CSS stylesheet `.link-group a { display: inline-block }` for when it eventually will be displayed. But this of course conflicts and make the element show immediately when the page is loaded - ignoring Bootstrap's `collapse`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/TheStoryCoder/fyyqygm3/3/

What is a good, clean solution to solve this? Would prefer not to use Javascript `onload` event to hide the element (it could cause element flickering on page load).

PS. The underlying problem is that CSS's `display` property actually covers two pieces of information: firstly whether or not the element should be displayed, secondly how it should be rendered when it is displayed. Seems to me to be a design flaw in CSS...

Comment: Please share your code or a fiddle.

Comment: @hunzaboy Done.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: @Quentin Isn't it standard procedure to provide a fiddle?? There is nothing in the fiddle that isn't described in the question. I have seen that so many times before so I don't understand why you made the comment...!

Comment: @TheStoryCoder — It is standard procedure to provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**. A live demo is a nice bonus. A live demo [in the question itself](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) is generally prefered over a third party hosted one.

Answer (score 2):

The collapse property hides the div, but in your case your other property is making it inline-block. The below code might sort your problem.

```
.some-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
}

.some-links .collapse{
  display: none;
}
.some-links .collapse.in{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add `style = height: 0px` to the element that needs collapse.
Hope this helps.